# See stdout of python script running through rc.local

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Inorder to run a python script at Ubuntu startup, I wrote the command in rc.local file as

```
/usr/bin/python path/to/my/script.py
exit 0
```

My script.py has some print statements. I wanted to know where I can see them while my script is being executed at the background.
I tried putting

```
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log
exec 1>&2
set -x
```

at top, but it din't show anything in rc.local.log except the sequence in which bash commands got executed.

I also tried writing in rc.local as 
`/usr/bin/python path/to/my/script.py > /some/log.txt &`
This din't work out either.

So how do i see the print statements of my python script running in background via rc.local?